# Why am I over counting the amount of comparisons in this insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: python, sorting, selection-sort

I am trying to count the number of comparisons taken in an insertion sort. Currently my comparison count measures more than it should, and I am not sure why.

```
def compare(data, a, b):
    """Returns True if element at index a > element at index b"""
    return data[a] > data[b]

def swap(data, a, b):
    """Swaps the element at index a with element at index b"""
    data[a], data[b] = data[b], data[a]

def insertion_sort(data):
    """Sorts the list into ascending order"""
    comparison_count = 0
    swap_count = 0
    for index in range(1, len(data)):
        position = index
        while position > 0 and compare(data, position - 1, position):
            comparison_count += 1
            swap(data, position - 1, position)
            swap_count += 1
            position -= 1
        comparison_count += 1
    print('Length:', len(data), 'Comparisons:', comparison_count, 'Swaps:', swap_count)
```

For example, sorting the list

```
[50, 63, 11, 79, 22, 70, 65, 39, 97, 48]
```

will over count the amount of comparisons by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `position > 0` isn’t true, `compare(data, position - 1, position)` isn’t evaluated, but you follow it up with `comparison_count += 1` anyway.

A straightforward way to fix it and combine the increments (at the expense of an overall more elegant loop) is:

```
while position > 0:
    comparison_count += 1

    if not compare(data, position - 1, position):
        break

    swap(data, position - 1, position)
    swap_count += 1
    position -= 1
```

which is also equivalent to

```
for index in range(1, len(data)):
    for position in range(index, 0, -1):
        comparison_count += 1
        if not compare(data, position - 1, position):
            break

        swap_count += 1
        swap(data, position - 1, position)
```